# How do I access serial port in RED?

Tags: serial-port, red

I need to access some weighing machines via serial port. How could I red/write data from/to it using the RED Programming language ?

Answer (score 1):

Serial port and most of I/O are not yet implemented in Red.

Please have a look at the Red [Trello board](https://trello.com/b/FlQ6pzdB/red-tasks-overview) to get an overview of the parts left to be done.

Answer (score 0):

As DocKimbel mentioned, most IO support is not yet implemented, but that does not mean you can't manually implement the functionality in Red/System.

The following information is pertinent if you are compiling for Windows.

To keep things simple I'd recommend following a polling approach as described in the first half of [**this article**](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/i-n/network/serialcommunications/article.php/c5425/Serial-Communication-in-Windows.htm).

Actually most of the functions you need are already in simple-io.reds. Specifically, you'll have to use the following functions under the simple-io context:

- CreateFileA
- ReadFile
- WriteFile

You may also need DeleteFileA, and GetLastError. simple-io doesn't import them (only the wide string variant on DeleteFile), so you'll have to do them yourself by importing it from **kernel32.dll** in **stdcall** mode. You'll also need to import [SetCommState()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363436(v=vs.85).aspx).

```
BOOL WINAPI SetCommState(
  _In_ HANDLE hFile,
  _In_ LPDCB  lpDCB
);
```

You will need a [DCB (Device Control Block)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363214(v=vs.85).aspx) struct for the second parameter.

Once you get it working at the Red/System level then can you wrap each of your basic com functionalities in a routine! abstracting out some of the low level c aspects and exposing the low-level code to your Red code.